# How to access row data upon row Selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) to display data.

I want to access a column's value when a row is selected.  I've implemented a `rowSelectionChange` event, but I can't seem to access the data.

`gridOptions`:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
paginationPageSizes: [10, 25, 50],
paginationPageSize: 25,   
useExternalPagination: true,
useExternalSorting: true,
multiSelect: false,
enableSelectAll: false,
columnDefs: [
  { name: 'Name', field: 'properties.Name'},
  { name: 'Address', field: 'properties.Address'},
  { name: 'PhoneNumber', field: 'properties.PhoneNumber'}
],

onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.mySelectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row) {
        var msg = row.entity.Name;
        alert("Row Selected! " + msg);
    });
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution by adding a breakpoint and looking at the value of `row.entity`. Changing it to `row.entity.properties.Name` fixed my problem.

Comment: Great job adding the bit about how you debugged it. Not enough people do this. However, it would be even better if you could add your final code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use row.entity.name instead of row.entity.**N**ame

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
paginationPageSizes: [10, 25, 50],
paginationPageSize: 25,   
useExternalPagination: true,
useExternalSorting: true,
multiSelect: false,
enableSelectAll: false,
columnDefs: [
  { name: 'Name', field: 'properties.Name'},
  { name: 'Address', field: 'properties.Address'},
  { name: 'PhoneNumber', field: 'properties.PhoneNumber'}
],

onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.mySelectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row) {
        var msg = row.entity.name; //change Name -> name.
        alert("Row Selected! " + msg);
    });
...
```